# sql - Get top parent of specified record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a standard nested category tree:

```
| id | parent_id |      name      |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |     0     |   Category 1   |
|  2 |     0     |   Category 2   |
|  3 |     0     |   Category 3   |
|  4 |     1     |  Category 1.1  |
|  5 |     1     |  Category 1.2  |
|  6 |     2     |  Category 2.1  |
|  7 |     2     |  Category 2.2  |
|  8 |     7     | Category 2.2.1 |
```

and now I need to get top parent of specified item so I do:

```
SELECT
    cat.*
FROM
    categories cat
LEFT JOIN
    categories subCat
    ON
        subCat.parent_id = cat.id
        AND cat.parent_id = 0
WHERE
    subCat.id = 5;
```

and if item is first-level child, it's working ok but is item is second-level child (eg. `8`) I'm not getting records - how to do this?
Here is SQlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5879bd/11

**UPDATE**
Here is real example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f1d1c/1
I want to get parent category of `Xiaomi`

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh I have updated question

Comment: Which version of MySQL do you use? And is there a maximum depth of the tree? If yes, which?

Comment: @stickybit : MySQL 5.6, yes - it's max 3 depth of the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL 5.6 you cannot use recursive CTEs.

To do it properly, for an arbitrary tree depth, you need to write a function/procedure, that traverses the hierarchy and returns the top node once reached.

As a workaround, when the maximum number of level *d* is set, you can left join the parent (*d* - 1) times. Use `coalesce()` to get the first non null value along the path. So in your case, for *d* = 3:

```
SELECT c.*
       FROM categories c
            INNER JOIN (SELECT coalesce(c3.id, c2.id, c1.id) id
                               FROM categories c1
                                    LEFT JOIN categories c2
                                              ON c2.id = c1.parent_id
                                    LEFT JOIN categories c3
                                              ON c3.id = c2.parent_id
                               WHERE c1.id = 10) t
                       ON t.id = c.id;
```

(I first select the ID of the top node and inner join the rest, to avoid `coalesce()` on all columns. It might give a false result on nullable columns if the value for the column in the top node is null but not for any child node. It should display `NULL` then, but will falsely show the non value from the child node.)

But note: It will fail if the depth grows!

Comment: Works very nice, thanks! "With MySQL 5.6 you cannot use recursive CTEs." - so it's another way for MySQL 5.7?

Comment: @Paul: MySQL 8.0 introduces that feature.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

To get the top level, you can use the `name` column:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c JOIN
     categories sc
     ON sc.id = 10 AND
        c.name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(sc.name, '.', 1);
```

Comment: It's looking fine but this categories names are only example. It can be for e.g. `Electronics > Hardware > HDD` - it does not has any `1.1` etc.

Comment: @Paul . . . Then ask *another* question with suitable sample data.  It is only possible to ask the question that you actually ask.